# Vuetify checkbox: how to stop the click event?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I tried to have a checkbox with a `@click.stop.prevent="myEvent"` that shall ask before setting the checkbox to true, but stop and prevent are ignored and the checkbox still gets activated. What might be wrong here?

Here is a fiddle with the described problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ag63f9fm/49/

```
<v-checkbox @click.native.stop.prevent='ask($event)' :label="`Checkbox 1: ${checkbox1.toString()}`" v-model="checkbox1"></v-checkbox>
```

the ask method:

```
ask: function (event) {
    answer = confirm('really')
    console.log('Answer: ' + answer)
    if (!answer) {
        event.stopPropagation()
      event.preventDefault()
    }
    return answer
  }
```

Comment: share any live demo ?

Comment: Try adding the `native` modifier: @click.native.prevent

Comment: In the event handler do you set/change the value of the property of the view model that the checkbox is bound to?

Comment: I also tried native after I posted the question. Didn’t help. Will try setting up a demo.

Comment: added a demo to the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, after posting an issue at vuetify I was told to use  `click.capture` instead, but I still don't know why a simple `event.stopPropagation()` **didn't work in the first place.**

Comment: event.stopPropagation() prevents the event from bubbling up to a parent element, while click.capture prevents the event from going down to the inner element. Based on what I know of Vuetify, the checkbox is probably an input element wrapped in a parent element. clicking on the parent element will always trigger the input element, so click.capture makes sense.

Comment: Thx for the detailed explanation!

Comment: I have to use `@click.native.prevent.stop.capture` instead... `capture` only doesn't work for me

Comment: @click.native="$event.stopPropagation()"
worked too

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem but with the v-radio-group. Reading the solution for the v-checkbox, I solved it like this:

```
<v-radio-group v-model="dateFlow" hide-details>
  <v-radio
    label="Not booked yet"
    value="NOTBOOKED"
    @click.capture.stop="openConfirmDialog('NOTBOOKED')"
  ></v-radio>
  <v-radio
    label="Already booked"
    value="BOOKED"
    @click.capture.stop="openConfirmDialog('BOOKED')"
  ></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

The dateFlow property is a computed property defined like this

```
computed: {
  dateFlow: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.getters["myStore/getDateFlow"];
    },
    set() {
    }
  }
}
```

The selectedDateFlow is a property defined directly in data:

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedDateFlow: null
  };
}
```

The openConfirmDialog method is defined like this:

```
openConfirmDialog(val) {
  // val contains the selected radio value
  this.selectedDateFlow = val;
  this.warningDialog = true;
}
```

Then I open a warning dialog and if the user press the cancel button I reset the selectedDateFlow property

```
closeWarningDialog() {
  this.selectedDateFlow = null;
  this.warningDialog = false;
},
```

Otherwise I use the selectedDateFlow property to update the dateFlow property in my store:

```
proceedAfterWarning() {
  // set the new value
  this.$store.commit("myStore/setDateFlow", this.selectedDateFlow);
  this.warningDialog = false;
},
```

I hope it will be of help to someone :)

Answer (score 0):

this code work fine:

```js
<v-switch  :input-value="checked" @click.native.capture="changeStatus($event)"></v-switch>
```

```js
methods: {
    changeStatus(event) {
        event.stopPropagation()
    }
}
```

Comment: `@click.native.capture.stop` without `changeStatus` achieves the same effect.